# Python - Shuffling a list with constraints

Tags: python, constraints, shuffle

I've been working for a couple of months, on and off, on a script to shuffle a list in a textfile. I am a beginner in Python (the only language I sort of understand a bit), and after a while I have managed to come up with a few lines of code which do sort of what I need.

The input file I have is a tabbed list. it has 5 words per row, but I'll make it numbers so it looks clearer in the example:

```
01 02 03 04 05
06 07 08 09 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25
```

Now, after a few efforts and a huge amount of work from SO users, I've managed to shuffle these elements so that they don't appear in the same line as their original "partners". This is the code I'm using:

```
import csv,StringIO
import random
from random import shuffle

datalist = open('lista.txt', 'r')
leyendo = datalist.read()
separando = csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(leyendo), delimiter = '\t')
macrolist = list(separando)

l = [group[:] for group in macrolist]
random.shuffle(l)
nicendone = []
prev_i = -1
while any(a for a in l):
    new_i = max(((i,a) for i,a in enumerate(l) if i != prev_i), key=lambda x: len(x[1]))[0]
    nicendone.append(l[new_i].pop(random.randint(0, len(l[new_i]) - 1)))
    prev_i = new_i

with open('randolista.txt', 'w') as newdoc:
    for i, m in enumerate(nicendone, 1):  
        newdoc.write(m + [', ', '\n'][i % 5 == 0])

datalist.close()
```

This does the job, but what I actually need is a bit more complicated. I need to shuffle the list with the following restrictions:

1. The words in the first and second column should be shuffled ONLY within their own column.
2. The new randomised list should have no two elements appearing in the same line again.

What I'd like to get is something like the following:

```
01 17 25 19 13
16 22 13 03 20
etc
```

So that items in the first and second column are only shuffled within their own columns, and no two items are in the same row in the output that were in the same row in the input. I realise in a 5 row example this last constraint is constantly broken, but the real input file has 100 rows.

I really don't know how to even start doing this. My programming abilities are limited, but the problem is that I can't even come up with a pseudocode for it. How can I make Python identify the elements of the first two columns so that it only shuffles them vertically?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't get the `1 2 3 4 5` to `1 7 43 52 15` part. Could you please update the question with something like a 5 line example of the input and the expected output?

Comment: Ok, you meant edit the original question. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shuffling the first two columns in such a way that two values that used to be on the same row do not appear on the same row can be accomplished by transposing the the columns with a random number. For example: you could push the first column 20 rows down and the second column 10 rows down where 20 and 10 are random integers less than the numbers of rows.

A sample code that randomizes the first two columns:
    from random import sample

```
text = \
"""a b c d e
f g h i j
k l m n o
p q r s t"""

# Translate file to matrix (list of lists)
matrix = map(lambda x: x.split(" "), text.split("\n"))

# Determine height and height of matrix
height = len(matrix)
width = len(matrix[0])

# Choose two (unique) numbers for transposing the first two columns
transpose_list = sample(xrange(0, height), 2)

# Now build a new matrix, transposing only the first two
# columns.
new_matrix = []
for y in range(0, height):
    row = []
    for x in range(0, 2):
        transpose = (y + transpose_list[x]) % height
        row.append(matrix[transpose][x])

    for x in range(2, width):
        row.append(matrix[y][x])

    new_matrix.append(row)

# And create a list again
new_text = "\n".join(map(lambda x: " ".join(x), new_matrix))
print new_text
```

This results in something like:

```
a l c d e
f q h i j
k b m n o
p g r s t
```

If I understand you post correctly, you already have an algorithm for randomizing the rest of the table?

I hope this is of any help :-).

Wout

Comment: You are a genius, sir. This is pretty much all I needed! The rest of the list can be randomised with the algorithm I had already. The ideal thing would be for it to make sure that c, d, and e (in the example) do not appear together (which it does already) OR in the same line as a or b, but I don't even know if this is possible, and I'm in too much of a hurry to care about that right now, so I'll just check and correct by hand. Thank you very much!